# I don't have slug as my argument in my function in view(I only have request), how do I get specific post with slug

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display number of comments in my index page just like I display it in post page. However, I don't have slug argument for my def index.

for my post.html I can display number of comments like this

```
  #for single-post page
    def post(request, slug):
            post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

            comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).count()

            context_dict = {

                'comments_count':comments_count,


            }
            return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

and in template,

```
{{comments_count}}
```

I want to do the same thing for my index page.

```
def index(request):
        try:
                sort = request.GET["sort"].strip()
                sort_method = SortMethods[sort]
                page = request.GET["page"].strip()
        except KeyError:
                sort_method = SortMethods.score
                page = 1

        if sort_method == SortMethods.date:
                post_list = Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
        else:
                post_list = Post.objects.all()
                post_list = sorted(post_list, key=lambda x: x.get_score(), reverse=True)

        paginator = Paginator(post_list, 30)

        try:
                posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
                posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
                posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


        context = {
                "posts": posts,
                "pages": paginator.page_range,
                "sort": sort_method.name,
        }
        return render(request, "main/index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a method to count comments to your `Post` model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    def comments_count(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post=self).count()
```

then use it in your template such as:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}: {{ post.comments_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: oh yeah I don't know why I couldn't think of that, thank you selduck

Comment: This is pretty expensive; better to use aggregation methods to add a comment_count attribute directly to the queryset of posts.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The results are already paginated but you are still right, for this case it might be a better approach.